# Cutting a string using sed

Tags: command-line, sed

There is a string, which contains numbers and letters in its name. The symbol '_' divides different parts of the string.

```
X23X_1XY4_XXXX_Y12Y_YYX2_XXYY
```

I want to have only second, third and forth parts:

```
1XY4_XXXX_Y12Y
```

Using cut one can do:

```
echo 'X23X_1XY4_XXXX_Y12Y_YYX2_XXYY' | cut -d'_' -f2,3,4
```

How to do it with sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use capture groups:

```
echo 'X23X_1XY4_XXXX_Y12Y_YYX2_XXYY' |
  sed -E s/'([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_.*/\2_\3_\4/'
1XY4_XXXX_Y12Y
```

For delimited data, awk is often simpler:

```
echo 'X23X_1XY4_XXXX_Y12Y_YYX2_XXYY' |
  awk -F_ 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $2,$3,$4}'
1XY4_XXXX_Y12Y
```